# Is there any way to take only part of string in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have some anchor links which has id's starts with `"menu-"`.

```
<a href="" id="menu-alphabetic">
<a href="" id="menu-city">
<a href="" id="menu-country">
```

In my jquery code, I want to take only anchor links' ids after `menu-`

```
For example:
$("a[id^=menu-]").click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).tab('show');
});
```

But `$(this)` takes all id. I want only word which comes after `menu-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.split()`

```
$("a[id^=menu-]").click(function(){
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#' + this.id.split('-')[1]).tab('show');
});
```

Also your HTML is not well Formed..

```
<a href="" id="menu-alphabetic">menu-alphabetic</a>
<a href="" id="menu-city">menu-city</a>
<a href="" id="menu-country">menu-country</a>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mGJdw/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like

```
$("#" + this.id.replace('menu-', '')).tab('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value for the `id` attribute, then parse the resulting string to get your desired result. From your particular problem, this would be done with something like:

```
$("a[id^=menu-]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var raw_title = $(this).attr('id');
    raw_title = raw_title.replace('menu-','');

    // outputs whatever is after 'menu-' in the id attribute
    console.log(raw_title);       

    //$(this).tab('show');
});  ​
```

You can see it in action in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxbzJ/1/) I made for it.